# Jump to Uiviewcontroller on handling push in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, push

I am handling push on alert to jump/open a view in story board like this from delegate

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iphone4" bundle:nil];
 ChatViewController  *scvc = (ChatViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatViewController"];
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:scvc animated:YES completion:nil];//not working show nothing while it works to jump using simple xib views.
```

and if i use

```
self.window.rootViewController =scvc;//it works but i need to get back on back button which causes it to get back in blank screen.
```

How to jump to a view controller using storyboard on handling push from delegate.
NOTE: The jump view have a back button,which need to dismiss the view too.
NOTE APP IS NOT NAVIGATION BASED

Comment: [self presentViewController:scvc animated:YES completion:nil];//try this for presenting VC as I got your issue till yet.

Comment: No self, its delegate, so [self.window.Rootviewcontroller.....etc work, but its not working for storyboard...even the identifier set is correct